# Function parameter precedence versus rest parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, apply

Below there are two object constructor Newobj is parent one and I want to create exact same object constructor with some extra parameter.

issue is: I want to use rest parameter but rest parameter can only send in last as argument, I also want some extra argument like home but (child2.home) is giving me ana1 output. it should give me 45. it will give name as jersey and address as 45.

```js
//first constructor 
function Newobj(name, adress) {
  this.name = name;
  this.adress = adress;
  this.fullA = function () {
    return this.name + " " + this.adress;
  };
}

//second constructor using apply method for inheritance
function Newobj1(home, ...args) {
  Newobj.apply(this, args);
  this.home = home;
}

const child23 = new Newobj("ana", "newport");
const child2 =  new Newobj1("ana1", "jersey", "45");

console.log({ child23, child2 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: "*I want to use rest parameter*" - you can't. Just spell out the two parameters.

Comment: I felt free changing title and tag-list since the OP's code features nothing close to inheritance nor to prototypes. ( Technically the code implements 2 constructor functions, with the 2nd constructor applying one variant of a mixin and the 1st function being used in a hybrid way of serving both roles constructor and function based mixin. )

Answer (score -3):

```js
  function newobj(name, address) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.fullA = function () {
          return this.name + " " + this.adress;
      };
  }

  //second constructor using apply method for inheritance
  function newobj1(...args) {
      const home = args[2] || "";
      newobj.apply(this, args);
      this.home = home;
  }

  const child23 = new newobj("ana", "newport");
  const child2 = new newobj1("ana1", "jersey", "45");
  const child3 = new newobj1("ana1", "jersey");
  console.log(child2);
  console.log(child23);
  console.log(child3);
```